# Match a pattern within any element of the data using data table rather than plyr

Tags: r

I have a very big data set and have not used data.table before. I am finding the syntax a bit difficult to follow. My main question is how can i reproduce the 'apply' function for a data table?

My data is as follows

```
dat1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), diag1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("I20.1","I21.3", "I48", "I60.8"), class = "factor"), diag2 = structure(c(3L,2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "I50", "I60.9"), class = "factor"), diag3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "I38.1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "diag1", "diag2", "diag3"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to add a variable for all records that have a diagnostic code either within the columns diag1, diag2 or diag 3 of I20, I21 or I60. Using apply and regex i have done the following.

```
code.list <- c("I20","I21","I60")    
dat1$index <- apply(dat1[2:4],1, function(i) any(grep(paste(code.list,
collapse="|"), i)))
```

I get the final dataset that i want is illustrated as below

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), diag1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("I20.1","I21.3", "I48", "I60.8"), class = "factor"), diag2 = structure(c(3L,2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "I50", "I60.9"), class = "factor"),diag3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "I38.1"), class = "factor"), index = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("id","diag1", "diag2", "diag3", "index"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

However this is going to take far too long using plyr. I was hoping to get the syntax for a data table. Would anybody be able to help?

Thanks in advance

A

Comment: Could you please check the data.  It is giving me errors

Comment: Sorry akrun - have fixed the error.  The code should run now.

Comment: Thanks for updating the data.  I posted a solution, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[, index := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, grepl,
         pattern = paste(code.list, collapse="|"))), .SDcols = 2:4]
dat1
#    id diag1 diag2 diag3 index
#1:  1 I20.1 I60.9        TRUE
#2:  1 I21.3   I50 I38.1  TRUE
#3:  2   I48             FALSE
#4:  3 I60.8              TRUE
```

Comment: Ankur - sorry to bother you again. The code that you provide works perfectly. For my own understanding what is the purpose of the syntax "Reduce("|",". What is Reduce doing? And what is the purpose of "|"? Thanks  in advance

Comment: @user3919790  If you check `setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, grepl,
         pattern = paste(code.list, collapse="|"))),  .SDcols = 2:4]` it loops through each of the columns specified in the `.SDcols`, get a logical column because we use `grepl`.  Now, we wanted to collapse the rows by checking if there is a single TRUE in a row and Reduce does that with `|`

Comment: many thanks Arun - a new weapon learnt for manipulating data!